# Voxel terrain engine

Tags: unity, terrain, voxels

Is there some voxel frameworks or extensions for game engines like Unity?
I really need a system to dynamically generate voxel ruinable terrains.

Comment: "Which technology to use" questions are off topic for the site. See the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here (and not ask). There's also a list of sites in the [FAQ] where you can ask more open ended questions like this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a good source for that [here](http://unitycoder.com/blog/2012/10/18/voxel-resources-engines-for-unity/)

Currently the free ones (with source) are:

- [Infi-Chunk](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63149-After-playing-minecraft...?p=1026478#post1026478)
- [Stacker](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63149-After-playing-minecraft...?p=404402&viewfull=1#post404402)
- [CubeField](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/83295-Learning-excercise-concocted-my-own-Minecraft-style-voxel-engine)
- [MetaBalls](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MetaBalls)
- [ChunkRenderer](http://unitycoder.com/blog/2012/02/15/dummy-craft-chunk-renderer-js/)
- [Voxel Terrain](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/95863-Free-Voxel-Terrain-Marching-Cubes)
- [Marching Squares 2D](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MarchingSquares)
- [Free Terrain 3](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63149-After-playing-minecraft...?p=811578&viewfull=1#post811578)
- [Terrain Generator](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63149-After-playing-minecraft...?p=780260&viewfull=1#post780260)
- [Cubic World](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgWM75QTr2o)

Comment: Links-only answer.